# What SF novel or short story features characters that can only communicate with musical instruments?

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, communication

I would like to find out the title of the book or short story that meets this criteria.

Science Fiction novel that the characters use only musical instruments (eg. saxophone, guitar, violin, piano, etc.) for communication with others?

To support my question here is an article "[Musical Instruments Used for Communication](http://www.ehow.com/list_6795710_musical-instruments-used-communication.html)" that shows that this type of communication exists.

Comment: Just musical instruments, or would a species that communicates tonally and with harmony (such as the Pierson's Puppeteers) be acceptable?

Comment: @neilfein I'd like for it to be just musical instruments but if there is no such novel then I can expand the criteria....

Comment: @zypher please explain why you closed this question.

Comment: Is this a recommendation question or a name that particular book question?  You might want to clear that up.

Comment: @Tony Where is the end of this list?

Comment: @zypher after the matching stories are listed.  If you mean that the list is excessively long, I'm not convinced that is the case.  If you have evidence that it is, please provide it.

Comment: @zypher this does not seem to be a subject matter that would have a large list associated with it, therefore it is answerable.

Comment: @Darius - I changed your title and added a tag, feel free to rollback my changes if they are not to your liking.

Comment: @Mark Rogers Actually this sounds better, thanks

Comment: @Darius - do you know of such a book, or are you just assuming there should be one?  I'm hard-pressed to think of such a work, and I don't think I've ever heard one referenced.

Comment: I was just assuming that there would be at least one story that has the idea I've expressed in my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Close Encounters of the 3rd Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_Encounters_of_the_Third_Kind)* had a lot of communication via music/musical instrument.

Comment: As being the closest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

[*The Moon Moth*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_Moth) by Jack Vance has musical instruments as one of the prerequisites for communication (nobody would listen to you unless you play one).

Comment: I think I should edit my question so it says that using musical instruments is the only way of communication.

Comment: Otherwise the songbirds in "Mikal's Songbird" by Orson Scott Card. They might actually be what you're thinking of, since IIRC they were not allowed to speak, only sing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikal%27s_Songbird doesn't say.